# C# memory management with filesystemWatcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, memory-management

I made an app watching a directory and notify to a textbox 
if the files are modified(renamed, deleted,created).

My Question is, this works well, but 
as the purpose of the program would be 
deploying it on the server for a long time, 
would there be a lot of instances of filesystemwatcher.
wouldn't be too much memory usage as time goes by?

And also, another thread is running on background 
dequeueing the string of the filename and uploading on the server.
After doing this uploading, it's ok to even delete the file.

In this case, is there a way to dispose the watcher in the updateDB method?

```
namespace watcherPrac
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private StringBuilder sb;
    private bool isWatching;
    private bool dirty;
    private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    //private StringBuilder fileNameSb;
    private ConcurrentQueue<String> cq;
    ArrayList watcherAl;


    private readonly string connectionString = "connection...;";

    public Form1()
    {
        watcherAl = new ArrayList();

        InitializeComponent();
        isWatching = false;
        dirty = false;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        //fileNameSb = new StringBuilder();
        cq = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        Thread updater = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sleepAndUpdate));
        updater.IsBackground = true;
        updater.Start();

    }     

    delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(string text);

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.testTBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.testTBox.Text += text;
        }
    }

    private void sleepAndUpdate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            while (!cq.IsEmpty)
            {
                string fileName;
                if (cq.TryDequeue(out fileName))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(fileName); // test
                    updateDB(OpenFile(fileName));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnBrowseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resDialog = dlgOpenDir.ShowDialog();
        txtFile.Text = dlgOpenDir.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void watchUpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isWatching)
        {
            isWatching = false;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            watcher.Dispose();
            watchUpdateBtn.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            watchUpdateBtn.Text = "Watch and Update DB";

        } else
        {
            isWatching = true;
            watchUpdateBtn.BackColor = Color.Red;
            watchUpdateBtn.Text = "Stop Watching";

            watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();

            // 
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.Path = txtFile.Text + "\\";

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                  NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            watcherAl.add(watcher);
        }
    }

    private void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dirty)
        {                
            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
            sb.Append(e.FullPath);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(e.ChangeType.ToString());
            sb.Append("   ");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            dirty = true;

            //fileNameSb.Remove(0, fileNameSb.Length);
            //fileNameSb.Append(e.Name);

            cq.Enqueue(e.FullPath);
        }


    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dirty)
        {
            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
            sb.Append(e.FullPath);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(e.ChangeType.ToString());
            sb.Append("   ");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            dirty = true;
            //UpdateDB(e.Name);
        }
    }


    // will not be used that much..
    private void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dirty)
        {
            sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
            sb.Append(e.OldFullPath);
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(e.ChangeType.ToString());
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append("to ");
            sb.Append(e.Name);
            sb.Append("   ");
            sb.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            dirty = true;
        }
    }


    private void tmrEditNotify_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dirty)
        {
            lstNotifications.BeginUpdate();
            lstNotifications.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
            //lstNotifications.Items.Add(fileNameSb.ToString());
            lstNotifications.EndUpdate();
            dirty = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I only see one instance of `FileSystemWatcher`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I mean, I don't know exactly how this works but I am guessing it would make each fileSystemWatcher for each file changed instances.. isn't it?

Comment: No, there’s only one wather and it tells what changed. There won’t be multiple watchers created anywhere.

Comment: The only line in there that I see that is confusing (and may leak) is `watcherAl.add(watcher);` That `watcherAl`, as far as I can see, isn't defined anywhere so I'm not sure how it compiles. Either way you only have one running at a time.

Comment: Oh.. Ok. I just assumed that the code snippet i referenced had an arraylist of watchers adding to it and I refered it so I thought it would be making multiple instances of watchers...

Comment: @RonBeyer Sorry. I missed it. Just edited the code.

Comment: You are adding it to the array list every time you click the `watchUpdateBtn` (actually every other time), you want to avoid that. Just remove the array list entirely. I can't imagine somebody starting/stopping the watcher with that button enough to create a memory problem, but it is holding references to disposed objects for no reason.

Comment: Even with an array of folders to be watched your memory profile will be small.  Unless a file hits a large number of the folders at a time, then it would depend on the processing you do when an event is triggered, not on the number of watchers.  A couple things to look out for that caught me:  If you're moving, or editing the files, apply a delay between the event being raised and the start of your processing, to allow the file to be completely written.  Some events are raised multiple times, build handling for this.

Comment: There is no reason to recreate the watcher, if you want to "pause" it, set it's raiseEvents flag to false, then set that to true to reactivate it.  As long as you are not creating more instances of watchers for the same folder you'll have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you guys!! I really appreciate all the help!!

Comment: Consider with great care what's been said about files that might be still locked when you try to access them. That's something that may ruin everything if you don't have countermeasures. Never assume that those file will be free to handle. It'll hit you in the face.